# Polly .Net shut down application gracefully with IHostApplicationLifetime

Tags: c#, .net, polly, retry-logic

The end outcome is to shut down the application if a specific type of exception (`DatabaseException`) has occurred.

However the current method `HandleDatabaseException` does not stop the application, the execution will carry on. Even though the `_applicationLifetime.Stop()` is executed.

```
private IHostApplicationLifetime _applicationLifetime;

public void CreatePolcy() 
{
    var policy = Policy
                .Handle<DatabaseException>(ex => HandleDatabaseException(ex))
                .WaitAndRetryForever(
                    retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
                    (exception, timespan) => HandleRetry(exception, timespan, stoppingToken));
}

public bool HandleDatabaseException(Exception ex) 
{
   _applicationLifetime.Stop();

   return true;
}
```

Comment: `HandleDatabaseException` should be used for filtering, not for taking actions.

Comment: If you want to stop the application whenever you receive a `DatabaseException` then you should consider to use [Fallback policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Fallback) instead.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem with Fallback?

Comment: Yes using Polly .net examples I created two policies. One was a fall-back policy which contained the HandleDatabaseException and another retry policy. Then wrapped retry inside the fallback (very important ordering or it will not work) [https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly-Samples/blob/master/PollyDemos/Sync/Demo09_Wrap-Fallback-Timeout-WaitAndRetry.cs]

Comment: Yes ordering does matter. To make thing simpler you should consider to use [Policy.Wrap](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) : `Policy.Wrap(fallbackPolicy, retryPolicy)`

Comment: Please post an anwser where you detail your solution and mark it as **the** answer